# Postman Native App - Add Root and Intermediary CA

Tags: ssl, postman

I'm trying to call an API which is hosted within an internal network and which presents a certificate signed by our internal CA. 
My question is how can I add the Root CA and intermediary CA to the truststore of the Postman native application.
I know I can turn off SSL certificate verification but I don't want to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To close the loop on this question - this is currently not supported by Postman. I opened feature request [3152](http://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/3152) to cover this.